# What can du see that rsync can't?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync, du

I want to copy an entire linux server that is going to be decommissioned over the network so we are sure nothing is lost.

I did `du /` and was told there are 60 GB of under /

Then I did `rsync -r / root@newserver:/old-server` and when doing `du` in the `old-server` dir I got 22 GB.

So why is that difference? Is there something that `du` can see but `rsync` can't copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have deleted files that can't yet be deallocated because there are open filehandles on them.  (I didn't previously know that du would see the usage from those, but some testing showed that it does.)  You can research this using [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).  The two main causes of this from my experience are deleting Apache logs without kicking the httpd and deleting mysql tables from the filesystem rather than by using DROP TABLE.

Comment: I think, this would affect df output, but not du.

Comment: That's what I previously thought, as I'd only dealt with it via df previously.  As I indicated in my answer, testing showed that I was wrong.  du turns out to analyze disk usage at a pretty low level unless you tell it not to with --apparent-size.

Comment: --apparent-size has to do with sparse files, not deleted files. du only counts files it can see, and it can't see deleted files.

Comment: This is really sort of fascinating, how people keep 'correcting' me based on the behavior du has *in their imagination* as opposed to, y'know, trying it.  Again, I have EXPERIMENTALLY VERIFIED that du will see the disk usage from a deleted file that has not been deallocated because of an open fd.

Answer (score 0):

There're some special filesystems which you should avoid copying with `rsync`, for example, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/tmp`. They may account for the difference you see, although, it seems too big anyway.

There could be some unreadable directories (for example, without `r` or `x` on them). I don't remember whether process running with `root` rights can access such directories without fixing permissions first.

Better generate and compare list of files and their md5 sums.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a bit of time on your hands, you could figure out exactly what the difference is:  run `cd /; find . > /tmp/old` on the old server, `cd /old-server; find . > /tmp/new` on the new server, then `vimdiff` the two files to see what's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) (use -S)
- [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) (use -H)
- `/proc` and `/sys` (use --exclude or, better, -x and backup each filesystem separately)

I tend to use `rsync -axHSW --numeric-ids` in similar circumstances.